# How do I connect an iPad to a projector?

Tags: ipad, video, projector, vga-adapter

How do I connect an iPad to a standard overhead projector? Currently the projector is connected to my laptop via standard cable.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a VGA connection, the `Apple iPad Dock Connector to VGA Adapter` might be of interest to you.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC552ZM/A

Comment: If necessary, you can connect the Dock to VGA adapter to a VGA-DVI adapter, and then connect that to a DVI-only projector as well.

Comment: Note that not all applications support video out, so make sure the app you want to use supports it before you spend 30 bucks on the VGA adapter.